# mongoose "Find" with multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to get data from my mongoDB database by using mongoose filters. The scenario is that each user object in the database has certain fields like **"Region"** or **"Sector"**.

Currently I am getting all the users that contain the keyword **"region"** in there object like so:

```
 // Filter all healthcare bios by region
 app.get('/user',function(req, res) {

 // use mongoose to get all users in the database
 User.find({region: "NA"}, function(err, user) 
 {
    // if there is an error retrieving, send the error. nothing after res.send(err) will execute
    if (err)
    {
        res.send(err);
    }
    // return all todos in JSON format
    console.log(user);
    res.json(user);

});
});
```

**How can put some conditions in mongoose that it return users that contain both "region" && "Sector" in their objects.** Currently its only returning the user which have the region keyword in them.

I have tried using $and operator but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: I see NO reason for a vote down. The question is clear and to the point and I have shown you what I done so far.

Comment: Or it's just a lack of showing what you tried to achieve what you asked and only a syntax error could be the reason why it was not working for you. So your mistake and not well researched. That's the criteria for downvotes, as "mistakes" are not really helpful to others.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

```
app.get('/user',function(req, res) {

 User.find({region: "NA",sector:"Some Sector"}, function(err, user) 
 {
    if (err)
    {
        res.send(err);
    }
    console.log(user);
    res.json(user);

 });
});
```

If you want data with either region:"NA" or sector:"Some Sector". you can use `$or` operator.

```
User.find({$or:[{region: "NA"},{sector:"Some Sector"}]}, function(err, user) 
 {
    if (err)
    {
        res.send(err);
    }
    console.log(user);
    res.json(user);

 });
```

Comment: @Vishnu, how would I go about searching for region = `NA` OR sector = `Some Sector`? I've been looking for this solution everywhere.

Answer (score 10):

If you want results that contain any region or sector as long as both are present at the same time you need the following query in your `User.find`:
   `{region: {$exists:true},sector: {$exists:true}}`

`,` is the equivalent of `$and` as long as you are searching different fields.

Comment: what if i want to find more than one documents that satisfy either conditions

Comment: @user3118363 first of all mongoose.find will always return all matches to your query, i.e. more than one document.  And to satisfy either condition you will want to use ``$or``, as in the above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33627306/1334781

Answer (score 8):

```
  const dateBetweenDates = await Model.find({
    $or: [
      {
    $and: [
      { From: { $gte: DateFrom } },
      { To: { $lte: DateTo } },
    ],    // and operator body finishes
    },
      { _id: req.user.id},
    ], //Or operator body finishes
  })
```

Comment: When giving an answer, try to attach an explanation with your code so that others can understand the logic better. see [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else trying to find with multiple conditions using mongoose, here is the code using async/await.

```js
app.get('/user', async (req, res) {

 const user = await User.find({region: "NA",sector:"Some Sector"});

 if (user) {
   // DO YOUR THING
 }

});
```