# MongoDB: add object to subarray if not exists

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I searched many questions here and other articles on the web, but they all seem to describe somehow different cases from what I have at hand.

I have `User` schema:

```
{
    username: { type: String },
    lessons: [
        {
            lesson: { type: String },
            result: { type: String }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to add new element into `lessons` or skip, if there is already one with same values, therefore I use `addToSet`:

```
const dbUser = await User.findOne({ username })
dbUser.lessons.addToSet({ lesson, result: JSON.stringify(result) })
await dbUser.save()
```

However it makes what seems to be duplicates:

```
// first run
[
  {
    _id: 60c80418f2bcfe5fb8f501c1,
    lesson: '60c79d81cf1f57221c05fdac',
    result: '{"correct":2,"total":2}'
  }
]

// second run
[
  {
    _id: 60c80418f2bcfe5fb8f501c1,
    lesson: '60c79d81cf1f57221c05fdac',
    result: '{"correct":2,"total":2}'
  },
  {
    _id: 60c80470f2bcfe5fb8f501c2,
    lesson: '60c79d81cf1f57221c05fdac',
    result: '{"correct":2,"total":2}'
  }
]
```

At this point I see that it adds `_id` and thus treats them as different entries (while they are identical).

What is my mistake and what should I do in order to fix it? I can change `lessons` structure or change query - whatever is easier to implement.

Comment: You can check for the lesson and result values (along with username you are already filtering on) in the query before the update (save).

Comment: @prasad_ so what you suggest is simply `if (await User.findOne({ username }, { lesson }))` condition (let's ignore `result`)?

Comment: Something like this: [mongoose “Find” with multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33627238/mongoose-find-with-multiple-conditions). The lesson condition can be coded as `"lessons.lesson": "math"`, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create sub-documents avoid `_id`. Just add `_id: false` to your subdocument declaration.

```js
const userSchema = new Schema({
  username: { type: String },
  lessons: [
    {
      _id: false,
      lesson: { type: String },
      result: { type: String }
    }
  ]
});
```

This will prevent the creation of an `_id` field in your subdoc, and you can add a new element to the `lesson` or skip it with the `addToSet` operator as you did.

Comment: It works now. Without `_id` it finally compares them right.